# Adding double values that are stored in an arraylist

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I've been searching for a way to do this and have come up empty and hoping someone may have an idea. I have an arrayList that is storing objects such as

```
{addToList, firstName, lastName, 1.0} 
{addToList, firstName, lastName, 0.5} 
{addToList, firstName, lastName, 0.5} 
{addToList, firstName, lastName, 1.5}
```

I need a way to add the values of the double amount from all of the objects, so I can get an output of

```
total amount is $4.5
```

Any help is appreciated =)

Comment: do you have a getter in that class for the double?

Comment: what did you tried?

Comment: @ChandlerBing yes I do have a getter

Comment: @Newb2Java then see Amonie's answer, does exactly what you want.

Comment: @Blasanka I've honestly had no clue how to even start this task, I'm new to this and while playing around with the code. Everything I've tried has a syntax error or just dose not make any sense at all when I type it out.

Comment: It is ok. If you can add your code we can get an idea about what you are trying and we can point reasons to errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is one solution to accomplishing your task:

```
double sum = myList.stream().mapToDouble(ObjectType::getAmount).sum();
System.out.println("total amount is  $" + sum);
```

where `ObjectType` is your class name and `getAmount` is the getter for the price within each object.